# pass a variable across multiple controllers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted a variable @user to be able to accessible across all the other controllers. How do i go with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
Class User

  def self.current=(u)
    @current_user = u
  end

  def self.current
    @current_user
  end

end
```

You have to set `User.current =` somewhere, for example in your application controller.

Then in another model or controller just call `User.current`

Comment: @Interpidd ,Its interesting that setting an instance variable works from a class method !. When you call User.current= on the User class, which user instance does it set on , when multiple users are logged in ?

Comment: ``User`` is an instance of ``Class``, ``@current_user`` is bound to the ``User`` class itself, not one of its instances.

Comment: So if 2 users are using the app simultaneously, which user would  User.current return , give that @current_user is bound to User class

Comment: If you use a threaded webserver, this code is not safe, You should instead use ``Thread.current[:user] = u``.

If you don't use a threaded webserver, requests will stack and the value will change for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a current_user function into your ApplicationController, something like :

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find( session[:user_id] ) if session[:user_id].present?
end
helper_method :current_user
```

You may now call current_user from all your controllers and views. @Intrepidd's method is cool too.

Comment: what if I don;t have the sessions and the logins available ?

Comment: With no sessions and no logins, what do you want to get when calling @user? nil? An empty User? You could modify the above example to return User.new when session[:user_id] isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are destroyed between each call to an action.

You must re-instantiate the `@user` each time.

To make it clean, you could do that in a `before_filter`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the current user (for example), you could make a method/function in your model and call that.